# Find duplicated values in an Array of Hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I am looking for a way to select only duplicate entries from multiple Arrays of Hashes.

Say I have a project with an attribute called "exchange_rate":

```
project.exchange_rate #=>
    [{"name"=>"USD", "rate"=>1.0},
     {"name"=>"EUR", "rate"=>0.91},
     {"name"=>"CNY", "rate"=>6.51},
     {"name"=>"NOK", "rate"=>1},
     {"name"=>"DKK", "rate"=>1},
     {"name"=>"JPY", "rate"=>113.24}]
```

Now I have multiple projects which have the same construct, just with a little more/less entries in the Array. The "rate" within the Hash isn't important at all. I just need to iterate over all projects and their exchange_rates and find those entries that are in each and every of the Arrays.

So to speak, if I had the following project_2:

```
project_2.exchange_rate #=>
    [{"name"=>"USD", "rate"=>1.0},
     {"name"=>"GBP", "rate"=>0.7},
     {"name"=>"SGD", "rate"=>1.38},
     {"name"=>"HKD", "rate"=>7.76},
     {"name"=>"CNY", "rate"=>0.94},
     {"name"=>"DE", "rate"=>0.86},
     {"name"=>"JPY", "rate"=>113.24}]
```

After comparing these two entries, I'd like to end up with an Array that looks like so:

```
# => ["USD", "CNY", "JPY"]
```

Because these three names are in both of the projects. This should, of course, be dynamic and work with whatever number of projects and exchange_rates.

I can't seem to find a way of doing this.
I tried the following already:

```
er = projects.map { |e| e[:exchange_rate] }.inject(:+)
founds = er.find_all { |x| er.count(x) > 1 }.uniq
```

But it comes up with a huge Array that includes all kind of values, not just duplicates.

TL;DR:

- I need to iterate over all projects and their exchange_rates
- I need to find all duplicated entries of these
- I need to end up with just the "name" value of these
- I have an unknown amount of projects as well as exchange_rates bound to each project

Thank you very much in advance!

---

I figured this isn't exactly what I need, so I changed my mind and did it differently.
Still, the question might be viable for others to get answered. If you have an answer, go ahead and post it :)

My (completely off-topic) result:

```
names = projects.map{|p| p[:exchange_rates].map{|er| er["name"] } }
final = names.flatten.uniq
# from => [["USD", "EUR", "GBR"], [], ["MYR", "GBR"], ["USD"], ...]
# to ["USD", "EUR", "GBR", "MYR"]
```

Comment: Your first method is close. Two things you should consider: (1) you only care about uniqueness of elements in `e[:exchange_rate].map{|r| r["name"]}`, not just the full values of e[:exchange_rate. (2) try looking into the `&` operator for `Array`. This finds elements in common between two arrays, while `+` just adds them together, which is why you're ending up with a huge array.

Comment: Okay. I figured how to just get the "name" values, however now I still end up with an array of arrays that I need to iterate through and apply & between all of them. Not only does that sound super inefficient, I can't also seem to find a way to automatically do that.

Comment: Without considering efficiency (and I don't think it's that bad anyway since the data size seems limited), try adapting your `inject(:+)`. This does a `:+` to each element, successively. Here we're looking to do `:&`.

Comment: Just to explore: To change approached for more computational efficiency I might construct a Hash with keys according to the `name` values. You could count, or for even fewer operations, add the value `1` to the Hash fir first time, `2` the second time you see a name, and never change that key's value again. Then, finally, you could scan the Hash for values that are 2 (or > 1)

Comment: Ahhhh, got it! My thoughts were going in a completely different direction. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply use `project_1.exchange_rate & project_2.exchange_rate`
, which gives you `[{"name"=>"USD", "rate"=>1.0}, {"name"=>"JPY", "rate"=>113.24}]`, i.e  common entries from both the arrays whose key and value match in both arrays.

But if you're looking for finding only the common elements in terms of keys of the hashes in the two arrays, you can try something like this

```
project_1.exchange_rate.map {|e| e["name"]} & 
project_2.exchange_rate.map {|e| e["name"]}

#=> ["USD", "CNY", "JPY"]
```

If you have multiple arrays like you said, try something like this:

```
def get_duplicate_keys(*rates)
    all_rates = rates.inject([]) { |s, e| s + e }
    temp = all_rates.group_by { |e| e["name"] }
    temp.select { |k,v| v.count > 1 }.keys
end

r1 = [{"name"=>"USD", "rate"=>1.0}, 
            {"name"=>"EUR", "rate"=>0.91}, 
            {"name"=>"CNY", "rate"=>6.51}, 
            {"name"=>"NOK", "rate"=>1}, 
            {"name"=>"DKK", "rate"=>1}, 
            {"name"=>"JPY", "rate"=>113.24}]
r2 =  [{"name"=>"USD", "rate"=>1.0}, 
            {"name"=>"GBP", "rate"=>0.7}, 
            {"name"=>"SGD", "rate"=>1.38}, 
            {"name"=>"HKD", "rate"=>7.76}, 
            {"name"=>"CNY", "rate"=>0.94}, 
            {"name"=>"DE", "rate"=>0.86}, 
            {"name"=>"JPY", "rate"=>113.24}]
r3 =  [{"name"=>"GBP", "rate"=>0.7}, 
            {"name"=>"SGD", "rate"=>1.38}]

p get_duplicate_keys(r1 + r2 + r3)

#=> ["USD", "CNY", "JPY", "GBP", "SGD"]
```

Comment: Problem is, as I said, I do not have just two of those projects, but merely like twenty to thirty.

Comment: @PhilM. check the updated answer for multiple arrays..this might help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution,

```
duplicates = project.exchange_rate & project_2.exchange_rate
```

and then

```
duplicates.map{|er| er["name"]}
```

This returns result

```
=> ["USD", "CNY", "JPY"]
```

OR You can try below solution.....

Firstly you find array of of names for both projects

```
proj1_names = []
project.exchange_rates.each{ |er| proj1_names << er["name"] }

proj2_names = []
project_2.exchange_rates.each{ |er| proj2_names << er["name"]}
```

this gives result like

```
proj1_names = ["USD","EUR","CNY","NOK","DKK","JPY"]
proj2_names = ["USD","GBP","SGD","HKD","CNY","DE","JPY"]
```

and then try below method

```
proj1_names.select{|name| proj2_names.include?(name)}
```

this returns duplicate names as result

```
i.e => ["USD", "CNY", "JPY"]
```

May this helps you..

Comment: Just like the other answer posted, this won't help me a whole lot because I have more than two projects. I do have like 20-30 projects, pretty much constantly changing amount.